# Swift ObservedObject 'self' used in property access 'userPreferences' before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, initialization, observedobject

[image]

I'm having the following problem can you tell me where I'm wrong?

```swift
import EventKit
import ServiceManagement

private struct PreferencesKeys {
    static let backgroundIsTransparent = "backgroundIsTransparent"
    static let isDarkMode = "isDarkMode"
}

class UserPreferences: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = UserPreferences()
    
    private init() {
        // This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.
    }
    
    private static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    @Published var backgroundIsTransparent: Bool = {
        guard UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: PreferencesKeys.backgroundIsTransparent) != nil else {
            return true
        }
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: PreferencesKeys.backgroundIsTransparent)
    }() {
        didSet {
            UserPreferences.defaults.set(backgroundIsTransparent, forKey: PreferencesKeys.backgroundIsTransparent)
        }
    }
    
    @Published var isDarkMode: Bool = {
        guard UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: PreferencesKeys.isDarkMode) != nil else {
            return true
        }
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: PreferencesKeys.isDarkMode)
    }() {
        didSet {
            UserPreferences.defaults.set(isDarkMode, forKey: PreferencesKeys.isDarkMode)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

You are going to modify `popover` before having initialized `statusItem`. This breaks the rules and this is what the error says.

**First**  initialize `statusItem` then set the background color of `popover`.

I would initialize `statusItem` even

```
let statusItem = NSStatusbar.system.status...
```

The code (text) in the question is irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't understand, if I do something like this it works:

`self.popover.backgroundColor = NSColor(named:"backgroundTheme")?.withAlphaComponent(1.0)`

The problem is when I use ObservedObject:
`withAlphaComponent(userPreferences.backgroundIsTransparent ? 0.3 : 1.0)`

Comment: Yes, `userPreferences` is actually `self.userPreferences`. Exchange the second and fourth line in the init method or initialize `statusItem` as constant as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Ok, it works but how come it worked the same before when I just put a numeric value as opacity?

Comment: Again, it accesses `self.userPreferences` before `statusItem` has a value, this is illegal.

Comment: I understand Thx, a curiosity do you know if there is a way to intercept a change of an ObservedObject object inside a class like the one declared in the image or in AppDelegate?

Comment: Actually `ObservedObject` makes only sense in a SwiftUI view.